# Why plusMonths, plusWeeks and etc are not public in java.time.chrono classes

Tags: java

In classes like `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` there are methods like `plusMonths()`, `plusWeeks()` and they can be used since they are public. However in `HijrahDate` class these methods are not public and they don't seem to be used in any class in this package.

What's the point of these methods if they're not (and cannot be) used anywhere ?

Answer (score 2):

The `plusMonths()`, `plusWeeks()` are meant to be generic for any calendar system, but the specific behavior of adding months, weeks, etc. can really vary between different calendars.

All these date classes use `ChronoLocalDate` interface, which has a method called `plus(long, TemporalUnit)` - and this is the best way of adding any amount of any unit of time to a date. The cool part is, each date class gets to decide how this method works for them, so if you want to add a month to a HijrahDate, you can do it like this, and be sure it's working:

```java
HijrahDate date = HijrahDate.now();
date = date.plus(1, ChronoUnit.MONTHS);
```

Read more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDate.html